# How to trigger child elements continuous

Tags: jquery

depending on which container I click, I would like to add a class to the equal box.
So if I click on the first container -> add class to first box.

In my script I have to write it for each container and duplicate it.. - but I guess there is a way to make it easier? At the end there will be around 100 entries

This HTML:

```
<div id="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">D</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="row-second">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

This Script:

```
    $("#row .container:nth-child(1) div.info").on("click", function() {
    
      $("#row-second div.box:nth-child(1)").addClass("show");
    
    });

    $("#row .container:nth-child(2) div.info").on("click", function() {
    
      $("#row-second div.box:nth-child(2)").addClass("show");
    
    });
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` to identify the element/div being clicked.

You can then use `.index()` to get where it is within its parent - there's a small issue here in that you have `row > container > info` so each `info` index will be 0 - so you need to get the `.container`'s index.

Then use `$("#row-second div.box").eq(idx)` to find the corresponding box

Added `$(".show").removeClass("show");` as the name *"show"* implies you want to show just the one being clicked and hide the others; obviously remove this if your use-case is to leave them shown.

Updated snippet:

```js
 $("#row .container div.info").on("click", function() {
    var idx = $(this).closest(".container").index();
    $(".show").removeClass("show");
    $("#row-second div.box").eq(idx).addClass("show");
 })
```

```css
#row div { cursor: pointer; }

#row-second div { display:none; }

#row-second div.show { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">D</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="row-second">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
$("#row").on("click", ".container div.info", function() {
  const index = $(this).closest(".container").prevAll(".container").length;
  $(`#row-second div.box:nth-child(${index + 1})`).toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
#row {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 1 0 2em;
}

#row-second {
  display: flex;
}

#row-second .box {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  flex: 1 0 2em;
}

.show {
  background-color: #0a0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">D</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="row-second">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```